# How to easily create games playable by email?

Tags: api, email, gmail, game-development

Say I'd like to create a turn-based text game, like Scrabble or Boggle, that can be played over email. What are the basic tools that one needs to make this happen? The most straightforward to me appeared to be the Gmail API, which allows one to read and send emails from a gmail account and take certain actions based on those. Are there any other options if (for whatever reason) I don't want to use gmail?

(Previously posted from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1017727/how-to-easily-create-games-playable-by-email), which was not the right forum for this)

Comment: With which language are you woking? There are some implementations of an email protocol in most languages.

Comment: C# and Python are my preference, but I found the documentation for the Gmail API for both of these languages to be lacking (which prompted the question, to be honest)

Comment: You could take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I would want to do:

- Think about how an email containing a move should be structured

> will the users themselves have to write this email?
>
> (if thats the case... good luck getting that to work)

- Write a parser that can read this email
- Write a gamestate server

> (represents the state of the board)

- Throw the email at the parser

> This is a bit broad but this could be done it lots of ways. Fetch the mail
> from a mail server, write your own email-server, use an API, ...

- Have it inform the gamestate server

> check for illegal turns, win/loss, order of play, reply with error if
> needed

- Update both players with the current state of the game

Thats how I would go about creating something like this.

PS: Creating a parser than can read mail that the players sent themselves should be a nightmare to code or the average user won't be able to play with this service.